# How to set value for hidden field based on selected option in drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, hidden-field

I have my drop down created in JQuery where I read values and names from array. That part works fine, now I would like to set value for hidden field that I placed above my select tag. So each time I change my option I have to set different value for that hidden field. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" id="userID" name="user" value=""/>
    <select id="selUser" name="selUser">
        <option value="">--Select Student--</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

JQuery:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       var userValues = [];

       userValues.push({'idOne':"31",'idTwo':"Tom, Poitras",'idThree':"88"});
       userValues.push({'idOne':"16",'idTwo':"All, Dirks",'idThree':"89"});
       userValues.push({'idOne':"15",'idTwo':"John, Reed",'idThree':"50"});

       for(var i=0; i < studValues.length; i++){
          $('#selUser').append('<option value='+userValues[i].idOne+'>'+userValues[i].idTwo+'</option>');
       }    
});
```

How I can set hidden value(idThree in my array) after I pick the student in my drop down? Should I have another function for that or there is some another approach for this problem? If anyone can help please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using jQuery's .change() event.

Documentation here:
https://api.jquery.com/change/

Something like `$('#selUser').change(function() { // what you want to do here });` inside your document.ready() function would attach an anonymous event to the dropdown.

Comment: I switched from onChange that I had in my select tag to JQuery .change and that works fine. Thank you for your help!